# Retrieving LookupValues, Javascript SharePoint 2013, Not Working

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013, lookup, csom

I've seen a lot of info on the above question but none of it has answered what I'm looking for, so far. I'm trying to retrieve list items that have a great number of lookup fields. I've had success getting to some of the lookup values but not others and I can't figure out why. Also, it would appear that 'null' items are not accepted in the returned data? If the lookup field does not contain a value, it throws an error? Is this correct? Below is my code. The other issue (the big issue mentioned in my title) is that lookup values where I'm trying to pull in something, other than ID or Title, throws an error: reference not found or initialized. In this instance my lookup field is referencing a calc column returned as a single line of text. So my lookup field is Course1Date/DateRange, where DateRange represents the fieldname of the calc column. Error: "The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested."

```js
function getLookupValues(){
    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Lookup');
    var caml = new SP.CamlQuery();
    caml.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Geq>' + 
                '<FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/><Value Type=\'Number\'>82</Value>' + 
                '</Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>'); 

    var returnedItems = list.getItems(caml);
    clientContext.load(returnedItems);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(success, failure);
    }
    function success(){
    var listiteminfo='';
    var enumerator = returnedItems.getEnumerator();
    while(enumerator.moveNext())
    {
      var listItem = enumerator.get_current();
      if(listItem.get_item('Course1')) {
        var course1 = listItem.get_item('Course1').get_lookupValue();
      }
      if(listItem.get_item('Course2')) {
        var course2 = listItem.get_item('Course2').get_lookupValue();
      }
      if(listItem.get_item('Course1Date')) {
        var course1Date = listItem.get_item('Course1Date').get_lookupValue();
      } //throws error for this lookup field

  listiteminfo += '\nCourse1: '+course1+'\nCourse2: '+course2+'\nCourse1Date: '+course1Date;

    }
    alert(listiteminfo);
            }
    function failure(){
    alert("Failed");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have initialize the fields to get Lookup Values. Have to load the ListItem in context. And if there is a null value in lookup field, get.lookupValue() will throw an exception. So check the field value is not null before getting lookup value. Please try my workaround below and let me know if it works.

```
 function getLookupValues() {
        var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Lookup');
        targetListItem = list.getItemById(82);
        clientContext.load(targetListItem, 'Title');
        clientContext.load(targetListItem, 'Course1');
        clientContext.load(targetListItem, 'Course1Date');
        clientContext.load(targetListItem, 'Course2');
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
    }
    function onQuerySucceeded() {
        var resultData = "";
        resultData += targetListItem.get_item('Title');
        if (targetListItem.get_item('Course1') != null)
            resultData += targetListItem.get_item('Course1').get_lookupValue();
        if (targetListItem.get_item('Course1Date') != null)
            resultData += targetListItem.get_item('Course1Date').get_lookupValue();
        if (targetListItem.get_item('Course2') != null)
            resultData += targetListItem.get_item('Course2').get_lookupValue();
        alert(resultData);
    }
    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
```

Comment: Hello Naveen, thanks for the response. Is there a way to pull in all lookup field values in the query, minus those containing null values?

Comment: I should probably change my query to be greater than or equal to 82. Code updated, to "Geq" 82

Comment: Tested above but it doesn't work. It only works if doing 1 item but not several.

Comment: To get many items pass Caml query. You can avoid getting null values by Neq <IsNull><FieldRef Name='[Your LookupFieldInternalName]'></IsNull>. Once you get the collection enumerate it and load ListItem. After that you get lookup values.

Comment: question: If I have multiple lookup values for each record, for example, course1, course2, course3, etc. and I want to avoid null values but still pull any course that isn't blank, how would that work? For example, let's say records 82,83, and 84 all have blank course3 but have course2 populated, can I still pull those records without error?

Comment: Would it be better to just bring in all lookup values (over 12 of them) and loop thru the results, filtering out null values?

Comment: I have modified my code, above. Pulling in courses seems to be okay. But as soon as I add the course1Date lookup, I get an error: 'The property or field has not been initialized'

Comment: You have to load the lookup field gain and executeQuery. In that execute succeed you can get the value. For Ex: clientContext.Load("Course1Date");clientContext.Load("Course2Date");clientContext.Load("Course3Date");clientContext.executeQuery(success,fail);

Comment: The other lookup fields, course1, course2, etc. all come in just fine with the code I have now. It's just the course1Date. I think I've already tried loading them but that didn't work. I'll try again and update this comment.

Comment: I tried adding, clientContext.load(returnedItems, 'Course1');  DId that for all courses (1,2,3). When I do that, I get, 'Course1' does not exist or is undefined